# ERR TFS001: ID 604114 local2.error filesystem is 100% full MTS - what is causing these messages?

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I'm seeing a lot of items in /var/adm/messages that say:

> Jul 23 10:31:01 server9008 *ERR TFS001: [ID 604114 local2.error] /mnt
>   filesystem is 100% full (MTS)

And they appear about every 15 minutes.

I wonder what is causing them on this solaris 10 server.

The /mnt drive currently has a CD mounted and therefore it is expected that the drive would report 100% usage.

`server9008` is the hostname.

These are entries are present in the `/etc/syslog.conf`:

> *.info;auth,mail,daemon,local1,local2,local3,local4,local5,local6,local7,user.none
>   /var/adm/syslog
>   *.info;auth,local7,mail,daemon,user.none        /var/adm/messages
>   *.alert;local1,local2,local3,local4,local5,local6,local7,user,auth,mail,daemon.none
>   /dev/sysmsg

Comment: It appears you have a file system monitoring application that's badly configured.  Assuming a minor cut-and-paste error, "9008" may be the PID of the monitoring process.  Also, any `local2` entries in `/etc/syslog.conf`could provide clues to find the application.

Comment: I've updated the original post. server9008 is the hostname. I have also add the relevant `/etc/syslog.conf` entries.